# Lime mortar mix ratio

Tags: structural

I am going to repoint an old interior brick wall (This is my first time) but the problem is that, I do not know what the best lime-to-sand ratio is? 1:2, 1:3, 1:1, 2:2 or something else? I want my mix to be white in color.

Comment: nit picky point.....a 1:1 ratio would be exactly equivalent to a 2:2 ratio.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Yes, but anyway, what`s the best ratio for an old interior brick wall?

Comment: If I knew I would have posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

All mortar contains portland cement, lime, and sand.

You ask what is the best "lime-to-sand" ratio, but what you should be asking is what is the best portland cement-to-lime-to-sand ratio. Brick pointing mortar is best mixed at 1-2-9 (by order listed above which is the standard mortar ratio order: cement-lime-sand) by volume. This results in a lime rich mortar that ends up being... sticky, in field terms.

To make it white, you use white cement and white sand.

Comment: There are [lime mortars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lime_mortar) without portland cement. They're typically used for restoration work. It's possible (although unlikely) that the OP really does need a lime and sand mortar.

Comment: Interesting... thanks for **pointing** this out (get it?). They say it has "remarkable durability" too.

Comment: Durable yes but preform poorly when exposed to lateral loads and collapse catastrophically when undermined.